# Having trouble retrieving value from radio buttons

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm currently working on my A-Level computer science coursework and straight out of the gate I'm having some issues. The plan it to have a quiz with multiple other features to it but I can't progress with development until I can get the questions to work, They are to be answered with thew use of radio buttons but when I try to retrieve the value of the radio box that has been selected (even when it is the correct one) the value I get is `PY_VAR0` instead of the actual value

```
def gettingDecision():
    var.get()
    if var == 'True':
        messagebox.showinfo('Congrats', message='You Are Correct')
    else:
        messagebox.showinfo('Lose', message='You Are Wrong.')

def ques1():
    root = Tk()
    window = Toplevel(root)
    Question1 = Label(window, text='Q.1.What data type is a whole number?')
    Question1.grid(row=1, column=0)

    Q1A = Radiobutton(window, text='[A] Str', variable=var, value='False1')
    Q1A.grid(row=2, column=0)

    Q1B = Radiobutton(window, text='[B] Float', variable=var, value='False2')
    Q1B.grid(row=3, column=0)

    Q1C = Radiobutton(window, text='[C] Int', variable=var, value='True')
    Q1C.grid(row=4, column=0)

    Q1D = Radiobutton(window, text='[D] Char', variable=var, value='False3')
    Q1D.grid(row=5, column=0)

    submit = Button(window, text='Submit', command=gettingDecision)
    submit.grid()
```

I know that the solution to this problem is probably very simple but I just cant get it for some reason, I have looked through posts on here for a solution too but I somehow couldn't find a fix. Sorry to be an inconvenience but I really need to know how to get the value to make any progress. (I will change how my code is structured with the use of classes at a later point but for now I just need this to work).

Comment: Have you tried searching this site for `PY_VAR0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things: the [Tutorials Point documentation for RadioButton](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_radiobutton.htm) says:

> If the control variable is an IntVar, give each radiobutton in the
>   group a different integer value

Second, this can't work:

```
var.get()
if var == 'True':
```

You really want:

```
if var.get() == ...
```

A rework, and simplification, of your example:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox  # has to be explicitly imported

def checkDecision():
    if var.get() == answer:
        messagebox.showinfo('Congrats', message='You Are Correct')
    else:
        messagebox.showinfo('Incorrect', message='You Are Wrong.')

def question_1(window):

    Label(window, text='Q.1.What data type is a whole number?').pack()

    Radiobutton(window, text='[A] Str', variable=var, value=1).pack(anchor=W)
    Radiobutton(window, text='[B] Float', variable=var, value=2).pack(anchor=W)
    Radiobutton(window, text='[C] Int', variable=var, value=3).pack(anchor=W)
    Radiobutton(window, text='[D] Char', variable=var, value=4).pack(anchor=W)

    Button(window, text='Submit', command=checkDecision).pack()

    return 3

root = Tk()

var = IntVar()

answer = question_1(root)

mainloop()
```

[image]